# Image can't be displayed when image is onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, onclick

***Functionality:***
When user navigates to the main menu page, a list of image will be displayed. When user click on a specific image within the container in the main menu, a second image will be displayed in a form of pop-up display image. 
Lastly, user can click on the second image and the third image will be displayed.

All the images are grouped into different arrays, all images are linked; meaning, ImageArrayA[0] = ImageArrayB[0] = ImageArrayC[0].

***What has been done:***

I have 3 sets of array of image source:

1.) All images source Array 2.) Secondary Image Source Array(pop-up display) 3.) Third Image Source Array

I have grab all images from array(All images source), and insert into a particular location say: `<div class="Container"> <div id= "list" class="innerScroll"></div></div>` . The images are displayed in accordance to alphabetical order.

Secondly, I have done an onclick in regards to the and append the second array to the first array, hence, when user clicks on the primary image in the main menu, the corresponding second image will be displayed.

Lastly, I have tried to do the same method for dispplaying the third image as that of getting the second image.

```js
var BrandNameArray = ['http://lorempizza.com/380/240',
  'http://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000',
  'http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/',
  'http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/sports/'
];

var SecondImage = ['http://lorempizza.com/380/240',
  'http://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000',
  'http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/',
  'http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/sports/'
];

var ThirdImage = ['http://lorempizza.com/380/240',
  'http://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000',
  'http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/',
  'http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/sports/'
];

var container = document.getElementById('list');
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

var x = 0;
BrandNameArray.forEach(function(url, index, originalArray) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.id = "Logo-" + x;
  img.src = url;
  docFrag.appendChild(img);

  var selectedOffer = SecondImage[index];
  //Choose Brand with popUp
  img.onclick = function() {
    $('#SecondImage').fadeIn({
      duration: slideDuration,
      queue: false
    });
    $("#Description").attr('src', selectedOffer).show();
  };
  selectedOffer.onclick = function() {
    console.log("index" + index);
    var PhotoFrame = ThirdImage[index];
    console.log("PhotoFrame" + PhotoFrame);
    $("#Chosen_ThirdImage").attr('src', PhotoFrame).show();
  };
  x++;
});
container.appendChild(docFrag);
```

```css
.Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 1260px;
}
.innerScroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 600px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #8d8989 !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="FirstImage" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index=3; top:0px; left:0px;">
  <!--Container to display all alphabetically sorted images-->
  <div class="Container">
    <div id="list" class="innerScroll"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="SecondImage" class="menu" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display:none; top:0px; left:0px; z-index=10;">

  <img id="Description" style="position:absolute; top:124px; left:534px; z-index=99;">
</div>

<div id="ThirdImage" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=14; top:0px; left:0px; ">

  <!--Photoframe that is selected from brand chosen-->
  <img id="Chosen_ThirdImage" style=" position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; top:0px; left:0px;" />
</div>
```

***Issue:***

I have managed to get the second image to display correctly when user clicks on the first image, however, when user clicks on the second image. The third image fails to load and display.

Meaning: when user clicks on imageA[0], i will get imageB[0] and also imageC[0] and if i were to click imageA[3], i will get imageB[3] and also imageC[3].

I would like to ask what have i done wrong. please help, thank you.

Comment: Based on your code, I can't see any elements to click. You have the containers all set to `display:none;` Please work with this fiddle to recreate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/9rsnkc11/1/

Answer (score 0):

`selectedOffer` that you are trying to add an event handler to appears to just be a string, not an element in the DOM:

```
var selectedOffer = SecondImage[index];
```

from

```
var SecondImage = ['ht_p://lorempizza.com/380/240',  
  'ht_p://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000',...
```

ie the string `'http://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000'`

The first image you assign on click to is an element you created with:

```
 var img = document.createElement('img');
  ...
  docFrag.appendChild(img);
```

You need `#SecondImage` to be clickable

Answer (score 0):

Well not directly answering your question, but I can suggest how I would go about creating the above interface.

Lets say that the images are having the ids with the `imgid` as the prefix and then their serial no or whatever unique id is there.

Then I shall add the pop images `absolute urls` or just the `name` inside the `data` attributes namely `data-first` and `data-second` respectively.
For this example, I'll go witht the full absolute URLs.

```
<div class="containerofimg">    
  <img src="xyz/img/xyz.jpg" id="imgid234" data-first="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/sports/FirstImageA" data-second="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/sports/SecondImageA" />
  <img src="xyz/img/abc.jpg" id="imgid235" data-first="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/sports/FirstImageB" data-second="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/sports/SecondImageB"/>
  <img src="xyz/img/pqr.jpg" id="imgid236" data-first="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/sports/FirstImageC" data-second="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/sports/SecondImageC"/>
</div>
```

Then I shall use the jQuery `.data()` or `.attr()` to grab the first and second overlay Images, and display them inside the modal.

As shown in this **[Demo](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/KzXWdd)**.